# Backbone call model function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection, from this collection I've selected a model. In this model I've previously defined a function. How can I call this function of model selected from collection?

Where I call the model function (but is undefined):

```
 var SingleHomePostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",


    template: Handlebars.compile(template),


    events: {
        "click #retweet": "retweet",

      },


    initialize: function () {
        // console.log(this.model);
     this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
     this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
      var ad = this.model.toJSON();
      ad.cid = this.model.cid;
      $(this.el).html(this.template(ad));


      return this;
    },



    retweet: function () {//Here----------
            console.log(this.model);// is well defined
        console.log("retweet");
        console.log(this.model.reTweet()); //here I try to call model function
      },




  });
```

and this is the model:

```
      var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({




 reTweet: function(){

     var params = {
                user_id: 11265832,
                //screen_name:"brad"
                page:1,
                count:2,
            };


            cb.__call(
                "statuses_userTimeline",
                params,
                function (reply) {
                //gestire rate limit error 429
                 console.log(reply);
                // return reply;

                }
            );




 }



  });
```

this is the main view that call previously view. It iterate on collection and pass model to the view.

```
 loadResults: function (eventName) {

        //this.showSpinner();
        console.log("homepostview"+this.page);

         this.isLoading === true;

            //console.log(this.IntegratedCollection);
            _.each(this.IntegratedCollection.last(this.IntegratedCollection.length).reverse(), function(model){

                 $(this.el).append(new SingleHomePostView({
                     model: model
                   }).render().el);



            },this);

            this.isLoading === false;;


          return this;



    },
```

Comment: This view accept a model from another view that iterate a collection.If i console.log(this.model) is well defined. If I create a var=new Tweet(); tweet.reTweet(), works fine. But I don't want create another model.@clintronx

Comment: what does `console.log(this.model.reTweet)` print out from the view?

Comment: can you add the creation of the view and where u set the model?

Comment: It kinda seems like your Collection might not be creating Models of Type Tweet and is just parsing the response into a basic Backbone Model. Please provide your collection too.

Comment: I've added iteration of collection and pass to the view. @clintronx

Comment: Still need to see the Collection class. Can you also verify that from your `loadResults` function when you iterate over the collection that the model you provide the View with has the `reTweet` method. My suspicion is it does not.

Comment: I've found the problem,it is because integrated collection is not the tweet collection father. This console.log show me correctly the code of function console.log(this.model.collection.TweetsCollection.models[0].reTweet);but if I try to invoke it with () show error:Cannot read property 'TweetsCollection' of undefined @clintronx

Comment: OK now works. Thanks so much your help was essential @clintronx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your collection should specify the Model type. [See docs for more info](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model)

UPDATE:

[From annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

To associate your model to a collection - that was not created by the collection via fetch - just pass the collection to model when you create it (assumes this.collection is your actual collection instance):

```
new Model({collection: this.collection})
```

Comment: Remain only a strange stuff:this.model.collection sometimes is defined and sometimes not @clintronx

Comment: I need to see how your collection is populated. Seems like you may be adding models to a collection that were not created 'by' the collection during fetch. I believe this will cause the model to not be  created with the `collection` attribute set. Try manually setting it via the options block on new Model(). Annotated source of a model: `f (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;` excepts a collection option

Comment: Yes you're right... I don't understand where insert 'f (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;' @clintronx